# Python CGI alternative for a small web-app

Tags: web-apps, python, web-development

I developed a small tool using Python/CGI. I'm reading everywhere that CGI is outdated and no longer considered as good practice. So I would like to re-develop my little tool using something more modern/efficient/future-proof than CGI.

Here is basically what the tool consist of: Users are sending data (a big string + some parameters) through a HTML form, and these data are analyzed with a Python/CGI script to look for specific things.
The data processing goes this way (but it's not important): a specific program (launch using a python wrapper) run and output some results. Then these results are analyzed one by one, until n results fulfilling some criteria are found. Then the “good” results are outputted as an HTML page.
The program may take a few second to run in good cases, and a few minutes in bad cases. It probably could be a little faster if I was better at programming, but not that much.
So the user submit his data, and wait for the results to display.

This is quite simple, but I would like to do things in the right way. Do you have any suggestions on what I should use to perform this kind of stuff, using python, instead of simple CGI? There are so many possibilities that I'm a bit lost... I read here that some people were recommended going with [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/). But I would like to be sure that I'm going on the right direction before starting to learn how to use something totally new to me, which will be time consuming. I would also like to be sure that I'm not doing a mistake by trying to use something else (overcomplicated) than CGI.

Comment: Relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777502/my-first-web-app-python-use-cgi-or-a-framework-like-django

Comment: Indeed, that's where I found the Flask suggestion I'm talking about in my post. It looks like it’s appropriate for my needs, but I’m still afraid that something like Flask could be a little "overkill"

Comment: I'm really a novice at this, but I've heard that Flask is great for simple sites so I'd try it out.

Comment: Okay, I think I'll try to learn Flask. I don't have the time to learn it now, but I'll give you a feedback after spending some time on it. Thanks !